# Why queries in cache cleaned every 30 mins?

Tags: mariadb, query-cache

I try to figure out, why my mariadb instance clean queries in cache. It happens every 30 minutes. It doesn't happen by cron or event scheduller. What i'am missing? Some mariadb settings?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 1471      |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 219999872 |
| Qcache_hits             | 203798549 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 65763537  |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 3758579   |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 1689178   |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 16441     | - flushed every 30 mins
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 35341     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

mariadb: mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

linux: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

[image: queries in cache]

[image: cache memory]

Comment: Does an `INSERT` occur every 30 minutes?  That would flush all the queries involving that table.  On a separate note, does your application run noticeably slower if you turn off the QC?

Comment: I found. It happens because mariabackup create incremental backup. Without QC my app work slower. When cached queries flushes during backup it leads to increase query execution time.

Comment: Let's work on improving some of the queries that need the QC.